# Detect changes in a tk::text widget

Tags: widget, tk-toolkit

I want to monitor every change in a tk::text widget.

My first step was simply to get all `<Key>` events and send them to my monitoring routine, but if I copy some text into the text widget, this will not work.

I found a `<Modified>` virtual event. This will give me the ability to react on every change in the text widget, but I did not find a way to determine the kind of change.

For my actual problem it would be sufficient if I got every character or text which were inserted into my widget. It is not important to get the positions or other attributes of the insertion.

The next thing I tried was to bind the `<Button-2>` event. This will give me a notification but I could not get the inserted text. Is there maybe a way to get the actual selected text from X which would be copied into the widget? This would also be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want notification of inserts, deletes and replaces (which all other modifications boil down to) the simplest way is to intercept the `insert`, `delete` and `replace` methods. Here's how to do it with a TclOO wrapper:

```tcl
oo::class create Text {
    unexport destroy
    constructor {w} {
        rename $w [namespace current]::realwidget
        bind $w <Destroy> [namespace code {my destroy}]
    }
    self method create {w args} {
        rename [my new [::text $w {*}$args]] ::$w
        return $w
    }

    method DoingModification args {
        # Override this method to find out
    }

    method delete args {
        my DoingModification {*}$args
        tailcall realwidget delete {*}$args
    }
    method insert args {
        my DoingModification {*}$args
        tailcall realwidget insert {*}$args
    }
    method replace args {
        my DoingModification {*}$args
        tailcall realwidget replace {*}$args
    }
}
# Everything else should just be forwarded; there's a lot of methods to do
# so we loop over them all...
foreach method {
    bbox cget compare configure count debug dlineinfo dump edit get image
    index mark peer scan search see tag window xview yview
} {
    oo::define Text forward $method realwidget $method
}
```

After that, you can make a widget and find out the modifications pretty easily, and everything otherwise works just like normal:

```tcl
set w [Text create .t]
oo::objdefine $w method DoingModification {method args} {
    puts "Doing a $method on $args"
}
pack $w
```

Comment: You don't need TclOO to do this — you can do it with straight Tcl scripts — but the code to do it is rather more complex; consider using Snit to do the wrapping in 8.5 or before.